# dd: reading binary file as blocks of size N returned less data than N

Tags: bash, file, binary, chunks

i need to process large binary files in segments. in concept this would be similar to [split](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html), but instead of writing each segment to a file, i need to take that segment and send it as the input of another process. i thought i could use `dd` to read/write the file in chunks, but the results aren't at all what i expected. for example, if i try :

```
dd if=some_big_file bs=1M |
    while : ; do
        dd bs=1M count=1 | processor
    done
```

... the output sizes are actually `131,072` bytes and not `1,048,576`.

could anyone tell me why i'm not seeing output blocked to `1M` chunks and how i could better accomplish what i'm trying to do ?

thanks.

Comment: **GNU Parallel** can split binary files into chunks like that for you and pass the chunks to multiple processes to be analysed in parallel, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to dd's [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html):

> - *bs=bytes*
>
>   [...] if no data-transforming `conv` option is specified, **input is copied to the output as soon as it's read, even if it is smaller than the block size**.

So try with `dd iflag=fullblock`:

> - *fullblock*
>
>   **Accumulate full blocks from input**.  The `read` system call may
>   return early if a full block is not available.  When that
>   happens, continue calling `read` to fill the remainder of the
>   block.  This flag can be used only with `iflag`.  This flag is
>   useful with pipes for example as they may return short reads.
>   In that case, this flag is needed to **ensure that a `count=`
>   argument is interpreted as a block count rather than a count
>   of read operations.**

Comment: `iflag=fullblock`. yes, the solution was as simple as that. embarrassed i didn't catch that in the manual - lol. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need the first `dd`. A `cat file | while` or `done < file` would do the trick as well.

`dd bs=1M count=1` might return less than 1M, see
[When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17295/187122)

Instead of `dd count=…` use `head` with the (non-posix) option `-c …`.

```
file=some_big_file
(( m = 1024 ** 2 ))
(( blocks = ($(stat -c %s "$file") + m - 1) / m ))
for ((i=0; i<blocks; ++i)); do
  head -c "$m" | processor
done < "$file"
```

Or posix conform but very inefficient

```
(( octM = 4 * 1024 * 1024 ))
someCommand | od -v -to1 -An | tr -d \\n | tr ' ' '\\' |
while IFS= read -rN $octM block; do
  printf %b "$block" | processor
done
```

Comment: yes, sorry, the dd at the start was leftover from the original pipeline, which is much more complicated than this example. we couldn't use `head` because it varied depending on the target systems. otherwise these are interesting approaches. thank you.